# Hand coded C# Coded UI Test , Control/Object location issue

Tags: c#, testing, qtp

I have a dropdown menu sub-item ("*logout*") that I want to select. I need to hover over the menu first to make the logout link appear. There's a lot of div's surrounding it; the spy tells me it's an `HTMLPANE`, but there's no built-in support for HtmlPanes in VS code as far as I can see. (I try typing it in and intellisense doesnt recognize it, not from htmlcontrols namespace)

Just before trying to describe this main menu object, I'm defining the variable as an `HtmlDiv`. I've even tried to identify it generically by referring to it as an `HtmlControl`.

Here's the "view source" of the dropdown menu in question. I need to get to the "Logout" link which is the bottom option in the dropdown.

```
<li class="my-account-top" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="doormat-profile">

        <span class="icon-profile menu"></span>
        <span class="profile-header tablet-hide"> Profile</span>

        <div class="ma-menu-items left">
                <a id="nav-my-account-profile" href="/my-account/profile/">Edit Profile</a>
                <a id="nav-my-account-profile-view-card" href="/my-account/profile/view-card/">View ID Card</a>
                <a id="nav-my-account-profile-request-card" href="/my-account/profile/request-card/">Request ID Card</a>
                <a id="nav-my-account-profile-logoff" href="/my-account/profile/logoff/">Log Out</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm not familiar with the `mouse.hover function. Can you please show me an actual example, preferably from this code? I'm not even sure if this is a way to identify it because from what I observed by recording the hover, browser resizing changes the coordinates.

I don't know if I am obliged to give a coordinate to `mouse.hover`, or can I just specify the name of the object control? (i.e. `mouse.hover(varnameformainmenu)`)

Comment: What do you want to do in QTP in this regard?